# Tuleap: Configuration of Bug Tracker report

Tags: centos-6, tuleap

I created a Bug Tracker and open different bugs. When I enter in my Bug Tracker, I see a web page with a search form in the upper part and a list with the different bugs in the lower part. However by default there are no information given for each bug. As I am administrator of my project I can configure the different informations given for each bug from the column widget on the right part of the web page. For example I can add Artifact ID, Submitted by, Severity, Summary, etc... But if I register my report with the blue button "Enregistrer" I lose all my configuration and the bugs list display no column. What is wrong ? How can I save the different information I want to display for each bug of my list ?

Bernard

Answer (score 1):

It might also be related to SELinux, can you try to disable it: `setenforce 0`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it happens to me. A workaround would be to hit the `Options` button at the right of report name, then choose `save as`.

Comment: That doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I looks like a bug on server side, a temporary directory not writable or something.

Is there any error in /var/log/http/error_log when you attempt to save ?

Comment: The errors list I get when save my bug tracker is in the following file: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1RIQRMwAdjpSFotR3JRRk4ta2s/edit

Comment: You have permission mimatch on /var/tmp/tuleap_cache. Try chown -R codendiadm:codendiadm /var/tmp/tuleap_cache

Comment: Done, but the problem is not solved.